# How to select datetime where isnull value from SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have `tb_user_log` to collect user login and logout history and it has two cols (`timein` and `timeout`) but if the system error the timeout col is null value.

I need to select it and display even is `null` or not `null`.

I have below code but just returns only where value is not null and it hide the recode where timeout is null:

```
select *    
from tb_user_log 
where cast(Logintime as date) >= '2018-05-16' 
  and (cast(Logouttime as date) <= '2018-05-16' or
       cast(logouttime as date) <= '') 
order by id desc
```

Is any incorrect point in my code? It does not return the null recode.

Or any better way to select it? My datatype is `datetime` and I am using C# + SQL Server 2012.

Thank you.

Comment: why don't you just check null? `OR logouttime IS NULL`

Comment: If you found the answer useful please consider accepting it (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test `Logouttime` against `NULL`:

```sql
select *    
from tb_user_log 
where cast(Logintime as date) >= '2018-05-16' 
  and (cast(Logouttime as date) <= '2018-05-16' or logouttime is null) 
order by id desc
```

Or you can handle `NULL` value in the condition:

```sql
select *    
from tb_user_log 
where cast(Logintime as date) >= '2018-05-16' 
  and (cast(isnull(Logouttime,'') as date) <= '2018-05-16') 
order by id desc
```

In both cases in the results you will also obtain the rows with `logouttime is null`